# How to schedule a job that runs every 2 minutes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have code generally that does this:

```
<every 2 minutes>
try
   <reap crops>
   <sow seeds via some api>
catch Exception => e
   <tell neighbor to take care of crops and this must happen>
```

and say I want to do eventually do this in multiple fields simultaneously every 2 minutes and I’m only in Ruby (not rails), what’s the easiest way to do this? Two approaches I’ve considered at using sidekiq scheduler or using the Thread class. What are advantages or disadvantages to both approaches? Take note that if the api fails, I need to get into the catch clause otherwise a lot of money is lost.

If I wanted to write this as a recurring piece of work that runs every 2 minutes (and this does not need user input), what's the best way to write this in Ruby?

Comment: If you're needing to run this semi-interactively, why not just loop it with a `sleep`, e.g. `sleep 2.minutes until Time.now > time + 2.minutes # breaks when true` if you need a specific time.

Comment: eventually I"ll need to do this on several different fields at the same time. I don't want it sequentially run but I want them run as close to concurrently as possible.

Answer (score 0):

@Jwan622 did you found a solution already?

I would go for sidekiq, as it offers many features like scheduled jobs, different retry options, a web UI etc.

You also need to think about situations like service restarts or deployments. I fear a solution based on threads will not be reliable (out of the box) in these situations.

---

Disclaimer: I maintain with [Sidekiq::Undertaker](https://github.com/ThomasKoppensteiner/sidekiq-undertaker) an open-source plugin for Sidekiq, which allows retrying dead jobs. I'm not involved in the main Sidekiq project and I don't get any affiliate fees.